# How to see IPTABLES LOGS?

Tags: bash, nautilus, gnome-terminal, iptables, navigation

i want to see some logs from an specific IPTABLES rules, i didnt set any path previously, so i think it may be the default path. The report below is the log im seeking.
[Iptables report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cms99.png)

Comment: version/distro of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

For the iptables listing shown, there were no logging rules and therefore there would not be any log entries. From the packet counter you can observe that 269 packets have taken the RETURN path from the SYN_FLOOD chain and 0 packets have been dropped. If you wanted to log packets that were going to be dropped, you would need to insert a LOG rule before the DROP rule.

Comment: so this should look like this?
`-N SYN_FLOOD` && 
`-A SYN_FLOOD -m limit --limit 2/sec --limit-burst 6 -j RETURN` && 
`-A SYN_FLOOD -j LOG` && 
`-A SYN_FLOOD -j DROP`

Comment: Yes, but if it were me I would use a unique log prefix for each and every LOG rule so as to make it easier to parse the information out of the `/var/log/syslog` file. For example `sudo iptables -A SYN_FLOOD -j LOG --log-prefix "SYN_FLOOD_DROP:" --log-level info`

Comment: thanks im gonna try